# Testcontainers for C# TCP Docker

Tags: docker, testcontainers

in our project, we use Testcontainers for C#. I am using a MacBook with an M CPU, so I am unable to run Docker on Windows. I have Docker installed on macOS and set up SSH to be able to set Docker context in Windows and use Docker.

However, Testcontainers does not use Docker context, and it does not support SSH.

My deamon.json

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": true,
  "hosts": [
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
    "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
  ]
}
```

.testcontainers.properties

```
docker.host=tcp://10.211.55.2:2375
```

Error in IDE

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot detect the Docker endpoint. Use either the environment variables or the ~/.testcontainers.properties file to customiz...

System.ArgumentException
Cannot detect the Docker endpoint. Use either the environment variables or the ~/.testcontainers.properties file to customize your configuration:
https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/custom_configuration/ (Parameter 'DockerEndpointAuthConfig')
```

docker info

```
Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 4
 Server Version: 25.0.2
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: ae07eda36dd25f8a1b98dfbf587313b99c0190bb
 runc version: v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: unconfined
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 6.6.12-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 11
 Total Memory: 7.657GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: 4fd473d6-2970-465b-a5df-3e3d5f4f695d
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5555
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: API is accessible on http://0.0.0.0:2375 without encryption.
         Access to the remote API is equivalent to root access on the host. Refer
         to the 'Docker daemon attack surface' section in the documentation for
         more information: https://docs.docker.com/go/attack-surface/
WARNING: daemon is not using the default seccomp profile
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my issue by using socat, as recommended in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/770)